# MS Access 2013 - How to Trigger an Event on an Automatically Updating Textbox

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have been banging my head against the wall for a while trying to get this to work.

I have an Access 2013 database. The db has a subform with a RecordID, Business Name, and Primary Contact in a continuous form. 
I have the active record being highlighted at this point.

The RecordID, Business Name, and Primary Contact fields are being passed up to the parent form so they can be used later for other sub-forms/purposes. I have a text-box in the middle of the parent form that I want to show the active record name in.

If the business name is empty I want to display the primary contact name and if the primary contact name is empty I want to display the business name.

I have gotten the if statement to work if i put the code in the OnClick event and I click on the RecordID text-box. Is there a way to trigger the event when the RecordID automatically changes without my interaction with the RecordID text-box.

Comment: Programmatically changing control value does not trigger events. Why using VBA and not simply an expression in textbox?

Comment: I assume you are only needing that box to display one of two field values rather than being able to update via that box? If you were hoping to be able to edit/update via that box, you'd have a logical problem as it wouldn't be clear which field you were intending to update.

If its the former, I'll post an appropriate answer for you below.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do this is to set the control source of the ActiveRecordNameTextBox to an expression.  Experience tells me you probably tried this but had trouble referring to the subform.  I always have to use areference when I refer to subforms.  Here is a reference that also gives some explanation:
 https://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/primer/index.html

if and only if is a natural choice for the expression given you want to select between two values.  So if you want to refer to the subform controls use something like:

```
=IIf(IsNull(Forms!MainFormName![SubFormName].controls("BusinessNameTextBox")),Forms!MainFormName![SubFormName].controls("PrimaryContactTextBox"),Forms!MainFormName![SubFormName].controls("BusinessNameTextBox"))
```

You could also refer to the subform recordsource fields directly.  Also when refering to a subform from the mainform you can use relative references to get:

```
=IIf(IsNull([SubFormName].[Form]![BusinessName]),[SubFormName].[Form]![PrimaryContact],[SubFormName].[Form]![BusinessName])
```

Note since you weren't explicit about the edge cases Like what to do if you have both a BusinessName and a PrimaryContact I just picked displaying the BusinessName if available and nothing if both where blank.